# Prove simple calculus integration property

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, suppose we are given function $h(x)$, cont, such that

If  $x\neq 0, xh(x) > 0$

Show that $\int\limits_0^xh(t)dt$ > 0

How do you show this?

Comment: Do you want to say $h$ is continuous?

Comment: If $xh(x)>0$ for every $x\neq 0$, then $h(x) = \frac{1}{x} \cdot xh(x) > 0$ for any $x>0$, and $h(x) = \frac{1}{x} \cdot xh(x) < 0$ for any $x<0$. Now,  the first part implies $\int_0^x h \geq 0$ for $x>0$, and the second implies $\int_0^x = - \int_x^0 h \geq 0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: @ClementC. Can you clarify the second one and maybe post this as an answer?

Comment: You have the statement "if $a<b$ and $h\geq 0$ is integrable, then $\int_{a}^b h \geq 0$," and similarly "if $a<b$ and $h\leq 0$ is integrable, then $\int_{a}^b h \leq 0$." If $x< 0$, you can use the fact that $\int_0^x = - \int_x^0$ to get to this case (the key point is that you have to use $a=x$ and $b=0$ for the assumption $a<b$ to be true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that, for $h$ continuous:

- if $a<b$ and $h \geq 0$ (and $h(x)>0$ for at least one point on $[a,b]$), then $\int_a^b h > 0$.
- $\int_a^b h = - \int_b^a h$

Based on that, you can prove your inequality for any $x \neq 0$, separating the cases $x>0$ and $x<0$.

- If $x>0$, then as $h(t) = \frac{1}{t}\cdot th(t) > 0$ for $t\in (0,x]$, you get $h > 0$ on $(0,x]$ (and $h\geq 0$ on $[0,x]$ by continuity) so $$\int_0^x h > 0.$$
- If $x<0$, then as $h(t) = \frac{1}{t}\cdot th(t) < 0$ for $t\in [x,0)$, you get $h < 0$ on $[x,0)$ (and $h\leq 0$ on $[x,0]$ by continuity) so $$\int_0^x h = -\int_x^0 h = \int_x^0 (-h) > 0.$$